# When PyQGIS script is run through console layer does not load successfully

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I made a small script to save a shapefile to disk. I want to run the script through console. When I run the script through QGIS IDE, it runs successfully. But when I run it through the QGIS Python command prompt it says layer failed to load successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils


_layer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/Arundhati/RadioSignal/MasterLine.shp", "MASTERLINE", "ogr")

if not _layer.isValid():
  print("Layer failed to load!")    
else:
    print("Layer was loaded successfully!")

_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(_layer,                                
                               "C:/Arundhati/RadioSignal/MasterLine12.shp",
                               'utf-8',
                               QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(),
                               'ESRI Shapefile')
```

I run the above file through QGIS Python console like the following:

[image]

Additionally Python also crashes:

[image]

What Am I doing wrong?

How to run the same script from outside the QGIS environment.

Comment: Have you tried to play it in the osgeo console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should review [Using PyQGIS in standalone scripts](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-standalone-scripts) for further information.

Also, try to run "OSGeo Shell" as @Oscar states.

[image]

According to the documentation, you need to change your code into (like) that:

```
from qgis.core import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.0", True)  ###

qgs = QgsApplication([], False) ###
qgs.initQgis() ###

_layer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/Arundhati/RadioSignal/MasterLine.shp", "MASTERLINE", "ogr")

if _layer.isValid(): print("Layer was loaded successfully!")
else:  print("Layer failed to load!")

_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(_layer,
                                                  "C:/Arundhati/RadioSignal/MasterLine12.shp",
                                                  'utf-8',
                                                  _layer.sourceCrs(),
                                                  'ESRI Shapefile')

qgs.exitQgis() ###
```

and run the script in OSGeo Shell:

> C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin> python3.exe "C:\Arundhati\RadioSignal\QGIS_test.py"

If you get this error: `Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec`, run `py3_env.bat` in OSGeo Shell, then run the command above again.